# Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS crashing

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS on free space on my shrunken hard disk to have it as a second OS alongside Windows 10. My PC has thermal throttling issues; thus, I need to turn off BD PROCHOT. I usually do that using Throttlestop on Windows, but I can't do the same on Ubuntu. After following a tutorial on how to turn off BD PROCHOT via the terminal, I put in the following after installing msr-tools:

sudo su
sudo rdmsr 0x1FC
sudo wrmsr 0x1FC 4005d

After that, everything froze and my screen turned black, but my laptop did not turn off. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? There's not really any description of the problem you are trying to solve. The only problem you've identified is that you can't turn off the laptop, but isn't that a hardware question? Please add an adequate description of the problem and the steps needed to reproduce the problem. To avoid confusion, put your question in the form of a question. Can you also provide more complete and specific details about what you did? Avoid summarizing in your own words because this doesn't actually tell us what you did.

Comment: An alternative solution to your problem is the "best practices" solution, which is to fix your hardware problem (overheating/throttling) with a hardware solution (fix your cooling problem). Laptops are designed so that they can run at 100% resources indefinitely without throttling. Throttling indicates a hardware cooling problem. Laptops require occasional physical maintenance to remove dust. As they age, they often need a removal and reapplication of thermal paste. If the cooling performance of your laptop has deteriorated, it will likely continue to do so regardless of software intervention

Comment: Sorry. My problem is that ever since I inputted the two commands above, every time I boot onto Ubuntu and try opening the terminal or a program, it completely freezes, and I'd have to shut down my laptop using the power button each time. Ubuntu was functioning fine, but a bit slowly, before I inputted the two commands. That's why I figured it was probably BD PROCHOT causing the slowness of Ubuntu.

Comment: You only wrote one command here and it doesn't follow the syntax of a bash/terminal command. I'm not sure it did anything at all. Where did you get that command anyway? In any case, your problem is overheating. It's not the sensor that is detecting the overheating problem and it's not the safety mechanism that is slowing/shutting down your computer to avoid permanent heat damage. You're essentially trying to fight a fire by pulling the batteries out of the smoke alarm. That's not a viable solution.